# How do I show the jumps list permanently in a window?

Tags: register, jumplist

As the title says, is there a way to view the jumps list opened in a permanent window? The question is also valid for registers list.

Comment: Hm, I just recently did this for the taglist. Might not be too hard to port to jumplist. However I would reframe from “is this possible” (answer: almost certainly yes) to “how do i” (answer: steps to do it)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you give me an hint about how to do that, please?

Comment: https://github.com/benknoble/tag-tracks for the plugin. I should also say welcome to [vi.se], and you can use the [edit] button to make changes to your post if you need.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! Yep, I've already used that button to change the title 